# Content Security Policy ( style-src ) when load from localhost:xxxx

Tags: javascript, html, css, nginx, localhost

**My Error in console is the below:**

> Refused to load the stylesheet 'data:text/css,@import%20url%28%27http%3A//localhost%3A8080/scorm/company1/scorm12/style/assessment.css%27%29%3B' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' https://fonts.googleapis.com https://fonts.googleapis.com".

**My Content-Security-Policy in http-header is the below:**

```
'Content-Security-Policy' "default-src 'self' https://fonts.googleapis.com https://fonts.gstatic.com http://www.google-analytics.com 'unsafe-inline';  **style-src * 'unsafe-inline'** ;
```

The problem is I used `style-src`, but why the error is occurring I don't know. Please help me and explain the detail of the error.

The most important thing is I am now using this policy in my business project.

So I want to be hurry.

Answer (score 1):

Why do you do double "wild-cards" (**) in `**style-src * 'unsafe-inline'**`?

It should be `"default-src 'self' https://fonts.googleapis.com https://fonts.gstatic.com http://www.google-analytics.com 'unsafe-inline'; style-src * 'unsafe-inline'"`

Comment: Thanks Malvoz, You are right.. When I already tested like this, error is still. I want to focus on localhost plz. I doubt the localhost name.. Thanks